# WPF ComboBox DropDown using PlacementTarget

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, relativesource

I have a `ContentControl` comprised from left to right of a `Button`, partition and a `ComboBox`. I want the `ComboBox` dropdown to line up with the left side of the control as opposed to the left side of the `ComboBox`.  I received a method in code but I was wondering whether if it could be accomplished in xaml.

This gives me the name of the control:

```
ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType={x:Type Control}}}"
```

But I would like a reference to the control:

```
Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=[Fancy-Smancy xaml goes here!]}"
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that a RelativeSource works fine if you specify the `AncestorLevel` and the `AncestorType` :

```
Placement="Bottom" 

PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=2, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"
```